# How to apply CSS after adding elemnts with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to add dynamically elements to an HTML page and applying the bootstrap 3.2 css's.

Here is the `jquery`  function:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".refresh-btn").click(function (){

        $("<div></div>").attr("class","row new").appendTo('.Item-List');
        $("<div></div>").attr("class","col-sm-3").appendTo('.Item-List .new');
        $("<div></div>").attr("class","panel panel-default").appendTo('.Item-List .new .col-sm-3');
        $("<div></div>").attr("class","panel-headingt").appendTo('.Item-List .row .col-sm-3 .panel-default');
        $("<h3></h3>").attr("class","panel-title").text("Panel title").appendTo('.Item-List .new .col-sm-3 .panel-default .panel-headingt');
        $("<div></div>").attr("class","panel-body").text("Panel content").appendTo('.Item-List .new .col-sm-3 .panel-default');
        $("<button></button>").attr("type","button").attr("class","btn btn-default btn-sm").attr("id","proccesing-btn").appendTo('.Item-List .new .col-sm-3 .panel-default');       
    })
});
```

the meaning of this function is to replicate the following code and add it dynamically :

```
           <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">Panel content</div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"
                            id="proccesing-btn">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>                  
            </div>
```

Here is the results that i'm getting , everything seems fine beside that `css` is not applying on the new elements that i added:

[image]

Comment: check whether the css affecting the html when it is static.

Comment: Beside your problem, that should a wrong jquery selector. the best way to do this, is create a div with all elements put class="hide" and when you click reset, just copy that content from the hidden div to the one you want to display. It will be much easer to maintain.

Comment: There are two images you have shown . Which one you are getting ? And `css` is not applied to which element ? Is it for all the elements ?

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle for OP: http://jsfiddle.net/nc8s2h62/

Comment: this 1 pic , the first box is the static one hard coded.
The second one is the one that has been added with the jquery function

Comment: @C Bauer this css file is bootstrap css file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a misspelling in this line:

```
$("<h3></h3>").attr("class","panel-title").text("Panel title").appendTo('.Item-List .new .col-sm-3 .panel-default .panel-headingt');
```

Change .panel-headingt to .panel-heading

Comment: Thanks! copy paste bloody mistakes :)